# Can't See the widgets at the bottom of NestedScrollView

Tags: android

I just hit a snag in my project that seems to have been an issue for a while now.

I have a CoordinatorLayout which has an `AppBarLayout` and a `NestedScrollView`. I'm working with the `CollapsibleToobarLayout` and it works just fine. The problem is that the `NestedScrollView` doesn't scroll up and down as it should. after the `toolbar` collapses, it doesn't scroll anymore, leaving the widgets below hidden.

I have tried `android:fillViewPort="true"` and `android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"` but there's no change. Here's the code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:theme="@style/MyMaterialTheme"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:id="@+id/appBar"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/collapsingToolbar"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="10dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="10dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:background="@drawable/bgPicture"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"/>

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:titleTextAppearance="@style/Toolbar.TitleText"
                android:layout_gravity="top"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                android:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                >

                <ImageButton
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/custom_trash"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_gravity="end"
                    android:id="@+id/deleteButton"/>

            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"
        android:background="@color/grey"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <TableLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:id="@+id/tableLayout">

            <TableRow
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content">



                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="100dp"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="false"
                    >

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:id="@+id/goalIdTextView"
                        android:visibility="gone"
                        />
                    <ProgressBar
                        android:id="@+id/progress"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:indeterminate="false"
                        android:max="100"
                        android:progress="60"
                        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/circular_progress_bar"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                        android:text="100%"
                        android:textColor="#000000"
                        android:textSize="20sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"/>

                </RelativeLayout>



                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:textAlignment="gravity"
                    android:layout_gravity="right"
                    android:id="@+id/progressText"
                    />

            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingBottom="5dp">


            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingBottom="5dp">

                <EditText
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:id="@+id/goalTitle"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_background_normal"
                    android:paddingTop="14dp"
                    android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
                    android:paddingBottom="11dp"
                    android:hint="Goal Title"/>
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingTop="5dp">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="@string/deadline_text"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingBottom="5dp">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/dateEditText"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:focusable="false"
                    android:inputType="date"
                    android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_background_normal"
                    android:paddingTop="14dp"
                    android:paddingBottom="11dp"
                    />

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/selectDate"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="0"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/date"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/select_date"
                    android:cropToPadding="true"
                    android:background="@drawable/calendar_icon"/>

            </TableRow>
            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingTop="5dp">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="@string/tasks_label"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <ListView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/listView"
                    android:paddingTop="5dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                    android:paddingRight="10dp"
                    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                    android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_background_normal"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

            </TableRow>


            <TableRow
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary">

                <Button
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textAllCaps="false"
                    android:id="@+id/updateButton"
                    android:textColor="#000"
                    android:onClick="updateGoal"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceLarge"
                    android:text="@string/submit"
                    />
            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Anything after the ListView doesn't show on screen, neither can it be scrolled into view

Comment: Add your code here so that we can see what issue is there

Comment: put your xml here

Comment: Done. Hope I find help real soon

Answer (score 0):

The standard ScrollView is only meant to be used as a parent. You need to change the ScrollView to a [`android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/NestedScrollView.html).

An example can be seen in the reference documentation for [`AppBarLayout`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/AppBarLayout.html).

Comment: you need to create NestedScrollView as parent layout

Comment: Didn't think of that.. By this you mean The parent Layout instead of the CoordinatorLayout?

Comment: yes in situations like these if you make parent layout to NestedScrollView then it will be less complicated and easily understandable. also add **android:fillViewPort="true"** onto it. If this helps please accept the answer and upvote

Comment: Unfortunately, That broke the entire thing irreparably.. Anyways, I am pasting the code so it makes it easier to understand

Comment: I'm still stuck on this. any ideas?

Comment: @AdamsonJeremiah please provide style you are using **android:theme="@style/MyMaterialTheme"**

Comment: @AdamsonJeremiah why are using TableLayout? I can convert it to LinearLayout and then design will be the same and hope that your problem will be resolved then